# "depend on his awful parents…"

Tags: participles

*When the babies arrived it would be difficult. She'd have to juggle her time between her family and his career. **Depend** on his awful parents for baby-sitting, or **hire** a nanny if need be*.

Can you explain to me why the verbs "depend" and "hire" have the form of the imperative mood in the above sentence. I would await present participle, i.e. "depending" and "hiring".

Comment: They're *not* "imperatives". They're just shortenings, involving the deletion of preceding text that doesn't need to be repeated. ***She'd have to** depend on his awful parents ... or **she'd have to** or hire a nanny if need be*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a shortening of the sentence

> *(She'd have to)* depend on his awful parents for baby-sitting, or *(she'd have to)* hire a nanny if need be

the passage could also have been written as a list

> When the babies arrived it would be difficult: juggle her time between her family and her career; depend on his awful parents for baby-sitting; and hire a nanny if need be.